# Is the space $W^{1,1}_0(0,1)$ an abstract $L^1$ space?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, banach-lattices

Let $W^{1,1}_0(0,1)$ be the space of functions on the interval $(0,1)$ that vanish at the boundary with the standard $W^{1,1}(0,1)$-norm.
$$||f|| = \int_0^1 |f(x)| \, dx + \int_0^1 |f'(x)| \, dx.$$

1. Is this space a Banach lattice?
   It appears to satisfy all the conditions listed [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Emjunge/banach13/BLAT.pdf). Two functions $f, g$ satisfy $f < g$ if $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \in (0,1).$
2. What about the condition $$|| f || = || \, \, |f| \, \, ||$$? Is this obvious?  Does one need to use smooth approximations?

3.If $f$ and $g$ are disjoint, then they satisfy $$ || f+g || = || f|| + ||g ||.$$ So is $W^{1,1}_0(0,1)$ an abstract $L^1$ space?

Any reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The condition on the absolute values is not trivial, but well-known (see for instance Evans's book "Partial Differential Equations").

Comment: Thank you. I tried looking at Evans. Can you point to a section or a theorem in Evans?

Comment: This is typically proved as a corollary of chain rules for Sobolev functions. Evans only has exercise on it:Ex 17 in 5.10

Comment: Sometimes (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_lattice ) the condition ``$|f|\le |g|$ implies $\|f\|\le \|g\|$'' is required for Banach lattices, which is not true for $W^{1,1}$

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that this other condition is required. Are these two definitions equivalent.  They do not appear to be.